# How to reprogram a piano for higher octave

Tags: piano, keyboard, digital-piano, octave

I have a Casio SA-77 piano with limited keys. I want to reprogram a button to increase my octave when I press it. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [user manual](https://usermanual.wiki/Casio/CasioSa77UsersManual243379.1029704625/view), the Casio SA-77 does not have the capability of changing octaves. The SA-76 and SA-78 also do not have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

It's always worthwhile reading through the user manual when questions like this come up. However, at the price this keyboard is, and given that it has 40 odd notes only, and even if you could, you'd lose the other end of the range, it would be impractical on an instrument such as this. If you need a larger range, a 61 'board will be the absolute minimum for practical purposes. Time to go shopping..?!